# Passing kwargs to parent class from inheritance relationship in child class

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have a parent class *RestResponse* and inheritance relationship with child class *AccessDeniedResponse* like this:

```
class RestResponse():
    def __init__(self, data=None, content_type=None, message=None, count=None, data_status=True, **kwargs):

        data_content = {
            'status': data_status,
            'message': message,
            'data': data,
        }
        if count:
            data_content.update({
                'count': count
        })
        super(RestResponse, self).__init__(
            data=data_content,
            content_type=content_type,
            **kwargs
        )


class AccessDeniedResponse(RestResponse):
    status_code = 401
```

when i call AccessDeniedResponse(errorMessage= 'You are not authorised to download.')
It will give this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ram/goenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
     response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/ram/goenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/ram/goenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/ram/goenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ram/goenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ram/goenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 505, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/home/ram/goenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 462, in handle_exception
   response = exception_handler(exc, context)
  File "/home/ram/gomech/crapp/crapp/handlers/exception.py", line 10, in cr_exception_handler
   raise exc
  File "/home/ram/goenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 502, in dispatch
   response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ram/gomech/crapp/crapp/rest_api_views/orders.py", line 439, in get
   return AccessDeniedResponse(errorMessage= 'You are not authorised to download.')
  File "/home/ram/gomech/crapp/crapp/responses.py", line 20, in __init__
  **kwargs
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'errorMessage'
```

Comment: Yeah, `errorMessage` isn't defined as valid argument anywhere, and `Response.__init__` ultimately "rejects" it. Did you mean `message` instead?

Comment: @deceze but there is **kwargs so all kwargs should get accepted.

Comment: But the super class doesn't accept it, see [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/responses/#response) and I assume line 20 is the `**kwargs` inside your call to `super().__init__()`

Comment: Even if you remove `Response` as a parent class, the problem stays the same. Now you're passing `errorMessage` as kwarg to `object`, which also doesn't know what to do with it.

Comment: Probably not a good idea to not inherit from `Response`. Just `pop` any `kwargs` that aren't expected by the parent class (and do something with them after you call `super()`).

Comment: @dirk Your class should simply accept any kwargs it uses itself directly by name, i.e. `def __init__(self, errorMessage, **kwargs)`. Anything you don't accept yourself, you just pass through as `**kwargs`. If the parent also doesn't accept it, then the fault is in the caller. No need for your class to play intermediator and protect the parent from faults of the caller somehow.

Answer (score 0):

`AccessDeniedResponse` doesn't have its own `__init__`, so inherits `RestResponse`'s.
`RestResponse.__init__` accepts the argument as `kwargs`, and then passes it to *its* parent:

```
super(RestResponse, self).__init__(
    data=data_content,
    content_type=content_type,
    **kwargs
)
```

Its parent is `object` here (*after you have [minimised the example](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59320446/revisions)…), so the problem can be succinctly reproduced with:

```
>>> object(errorMessage='foo')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: object() takes no arguments
```

In other words, *passing the argument through* works just fine as expected. There's just nothing in the chain of inheritance which accepts that particular keyword argument.

Comment: OP is not inheriting from `object` actually, so `super()` will raise another error, something saying that there isn't a super class.

Comment: It *implicitly* inherits from object. The exact error message here would be `TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)`.